# Networking between PODS, CONTAINERS & NODES

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have GKE to create a Kubernetes cluster, which is having 2 nodes and i have created a deployment to download nginx image with 2 replicas. Now that i have nginx images running on the same node ( NODE 1 ) , i am able to login to NODE 2 and curl the PODIP of NODE1 .

I would like to understand , how communication between container in NODE 1 and NODE 2 even though am not using port 80 of the node.

Appreciate some insights on the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by reading an overview on [Networking in Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/networking/). The question you are asking is about the *overlay network*. The exact workings of the overlay network is viewed as an implementation detail and there are many different networking solutions (GKE is running on [GCE](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/networking/#google-compute-engine-gce)). GKE is using [`kubenet`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/network-plugins/#kubenet).

You might find the talk [*Illustrated Guide To Kubernetes Networking*](https://speakerdeck.com/thockin/illustrated-guide-to-kubernetes-networking) useful.

Comment: This help a lot for me